# Unable to access certain file types via Rails public folder on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4

We're hosting a Rails app on Heroku, and having some trouble serving *some* static assets out of the public folder. (I know, this isn't recommended. We actually use CloudFront with a custom origin of our main application so we're getting the benefit of a CDN still. But that's irrelevant for this issue.)

Some assets serve up fine and exactly as expected. Ex: `/404.html`, `/favicon.png`

Others return an HTTP 406 error: `/video-js/swf/video-js-4.1.0.swf`

Rails 4.1.1

Ruby 2.1.2

The `rails_12factor` gem is present.

production.rb file sets `config.serve_static_assets = true`

The file definitely exists.. Using the console on Heroku:

`File.size("/app/public/video-js/swf/video-js-4.1.0.swf")
=> 14059`

But when I try to access the file, I get an `HTTP 406 Not Acceptable` response

`curl -I http://my-rails-application.com/video-js/swf/video-js-4.1.0.swf`

returns:

`HTTP/1.1 406 Not Acceptable
Content-length: 0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Date: Wed, 04 Jun 2014 02:25:37 GMT
Status: 406 Not Acceptable
X-Request-Id: d184b097-7326-49cb-ad05-539459f7df08
X-Runtime: 0.532988
Connection: keep-alive`

I tried adding a Mime Type for swf files (`Mime::Type.register "application/x-shockwave-flash", :swf`) and now I get a 404 instead of a 406, but that's still not very useful.

To recap, html, png, jpg, ico, and txt files all are served perfectly. swf, ttf, woff and a few others aren't being served out of the public folder.

What could cause some file types in the public folder to work properly, but not others?

Comment: Which browser are you using?

Comment: Same result in Chrome, Firefox, and Safari. See the curl request that also shows the 406 response in my question.

Comment: Can you serve content in directories in Heroku that are not predefined.  I suspect is a question for the Heroku team, not necessarily a rails issue.

Comment: Did you solve this?